# ImageMagic: 'convert' command : PDF convertion with bad size/orientation

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I'm using the next command in perl:

```
$mycomm="convert -density 288 doc.pdf -resize 25% doc.png"; 
system ($mycomm);
```

The problem comes when i see the output , i see this problem:
[image]

P.D: I have test -size , -resize , and -geometry params without good output

Any idea? , Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Perl. Rather it is related to the command line utility `convert` which I believe comes with ImageMagick.

Comment: Language i'm using is perl cgi-bin , and i was using ImageMagic with the same result . Maybe i must change tags.

Comment: I understand the problem of tags , but i don't know why you have voted to close it.

Comment: You do not have a programming problem. You have a problem using a specific file conversion utility. As such, your question belongs on SuperUser rather than StackOverflow which is dedicated to answering *programming* questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bad formated pdf error.

Comment: what exactly was wrong with the pdf? i am having the same problem